# How to use behaviors when operating as RESTful?

Tags: rest, yii, yii2

I am following the instructions* on how to create a RESTful service with Yii2 but the behavior method causes the error:

`Response content must not be an array.`

If I remove the behavior method then I receive the JSON response that I expect. I tried removing the behavior method after reading another post**.

However I am a little unfamiliar with behaviors. Can we not use behaviors with Yii2 with REST or is this a bug? I would be very appreciate if someone could shed some light on this.

*http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html
**http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/60432-rest-api-failing-with-behaviours/

Comment: Can you post the content of your controller? It might shed some light on the problem.

Comment: I can't post the content because it contains for characters than StackOverflow allow. You can see it on Github however. Note that I renamed behaviors() to get it to work. Rename it to test.                  https://github.com/doublehops/yii2-learn/blob/master/app/frontend/controllers/UserController.php

Answer (score 8):

Your problem is that you have overridden the behaviors() method completely. The parent classes have behaviors attached that negotiate the content headers and response format. To get round this your behaviors needs to return an array merged with the parent behaviors. So your behaviors() method will look like this;

```
public function behaviors() {
    return ArrayHelper::merge(parent::behaviors(), [
                'verbs' => [
                    'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                    'actions' => [
                        'delete' => ['post'],
                    ],
                ],
    ]);
}
```

You need to remember to add `use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper` at the top of the controller class.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have made this change but I am now confused on two points: 1) It doesn't seem to call UserController->actionView() for me to make changes to and 2) How do I add a behavior here that would allow me for example, update created_at and updated_at attributes?

Comment: OK, I worked out how I should be updating created_at and updated_at using behaviours in this post: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/concept-behaviors.md